# Wordpress hosted on EC2 overloads the server

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have hosted a wordpress website on Amazon EC2 t2.medium server instance.

The OS is 64-bit Ubuntu 16.x.x version

The issue is that, after the server is up for about 2-3 days, the server suddenly overloads and stops responding.

I am not sure what is triggering this overload on the server.

When I stop the apache server, the load gradually decreases, and restarting the server after few minutes fixes the problem.

Here is the load info,

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-127:~$ uptime
 12:42:43 up 6 days, 49 min,  2 users,  load average: 32.58, 63.91, 34.88
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-127:~$ uptime
 12:42:47 up 6 days, 49 min,  2 users,  load average: 29.97, 62.85, 34.69
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-127:~$ uptime
 12:42:50 up 6 days, 49 min,  2 users,  load average: 27.57, 61.80, 34.50
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-127:~$ uptime
 12:42:54 up 6 days, 49 min,  2 users,  load average: 25.36, 60.78, 34.32
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-127:~$ uptime
 12:43:27 up 6 days, 49 min,  2 users,  load average: 15.37, 54.97, 33.22
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-127:~$ uptime
 12:51:15 up 6 days, 57 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 11.38, 20.01
```

has anyone had the same kind of issue with wordpress on EC2? Is it triggered by some plugin or is my server configuration wrong?

Thank you in advance.

***EDIT***
I looked into the apache access and error logs,

**access logs**

```
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:10 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:06 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:09 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.53 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:05 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:02 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:03 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.53 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:07 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 52.58.212.131 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:35 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1475.3754720687866210937500 HTTP/1.1" 200 166 "http://52.58.212.131/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1475.3754720687866210937500" "WordPress/4.6.1; http://52.58.212.131"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:06 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:03 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.54 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:15 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
 191.96.249.53 - - [05/Oct/2016:07:56:11 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 560 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

**error logs**

```
[Wed Oct 05 06:25:27.206451 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27426] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 05 06:25:27.206490 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27426] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00005629347d6910 ***
[Wed Oct 05 07:57:13.804332 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27426] AH00051: child pid 11014 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Oct 05 07:57:14.806735 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27426] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I suppose this is where the server is overloading, and apache stops responding.

Comment: What is the exact instance type? (There are a few that have medium in their name.) Is there anything in the Apache log?

Comment: @jbird thanks for the response, the instance type is t2.medium, 4GB main memory, 2 vCPUs, 24 CPU credits per hour. And I have 30GB EBS storage.  I have updated access and error logs in question.

Comment: I've hit the error you describe but it's usually on smaller instances like t2.small, t2.micro, and t2.nano. However, that website got very little traffic. The problem in my case was mostly attributed to the MySQL database running on the instance, too. If you can, I'd try to separate the database from the instance and see if it helps.